# Windows 10 use less RAM to allow multiple virtual machines

Tags: windows, memory, virtual-machine

I recently upgraded my laptop from 12GB RAM to 24GB RAM (Win10). One of the reasons is to run two virtual machines (both 8GB RAM, both Linux using VMware Player) at once. After the Upgrade, though, everything seems to consume more memory (especially browsers, but also the system as a whole). After a bit of usage I am idling at 6-8GB RAM used with everything closed.

The RAM is not properly freed up even when I power on both said machines at the same time which leads to loads of swapping.

Before I was running one VM with 6GB using Firefox and even other apps a lot, and could even run the VM with 8GB (then I had to close Firefox though). This makes me think the increase in RAM makes the system use more of it. Is there any way to mitigate this?

I understand that unused RAM is wasted RAM in general, but in my specific situation, this behavior seems very counterproductive.

Comment: You really spend only three words describing the actual problem, "loads of swapping". Can you give us some more details? How much swap is being used? When do you see the swapping? When launching new applications? During general use? Or what? Is switching between applications slow? Is using normal applications slow?

Comment: Once I power on the second 8GB virtual machine, my RAM i eaten up within a few minutes (RAM usage of VMs usually ramps up a bit at start), I have no memory left, normal usage becomes really laggy, and my hard drive is at 100% constantly (due to using the pagefile). Launching new applications, and general I/O operations become slow too. Typical usage would be said 2 VMs and a browser.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that disk I/O is due to using the pagefile? I think it's quite likely that your three OSes (two virtual, one the host) are just doing a lot of disk I/O. The reason so much RAM is being used is to try to minimize that disk I/O. Do you have a decent SSD or are you using spinning disk? (More details in your question would help. You're asking us to troubleshoot a complex problem with minimal information.)

Comment: I'm thinking it must be the pagefile, because it is always the disk, where I have it on. I have a 1TB HDD, a 128GB SSD and a (new) 1TB SSD. The host OS is on the 128SSD, the VMs are both on the 1TB SSD. I have put the pagefile on all 3 of the drives, and it always shows the activity on that very drive. Also, everything becomes way worse when the Pagefile is on the HDD, because it is a lot slower, especially with a pagefile. I also checked pagefile usage in the performance monitor, it is around 3GB in that setup (shows 25% with a 12GB pagefile).

Comment: That's very odd. You seem to have some unusual problem as what you're describing is not typical. It may be worth running this test: Remove the pagefile so only RAM is available. Let the machine run until you start to see performance issues. Then use [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap) to see what the memory is being used by. It could even be a bad driver or something odd like that.

Comment: It might actually be Firefox. I've been having RAM and some paging again just now when opening some older Tabs in Firefox. While it showed to be around 800MB in the Task Manager, around 7GB of Memory actually freed up after closing it. Can that be a thing?

Comment: UPDATE: Firefox (or more precisely: some addons) actually seems to be the issue. The problem is reproducable and goes away when I start Firefox in save mode. The weird thing is that the memory is not shown associated to the Firefox process in the Task manager, but multiple GB of RAM go away as soon as I close it.

Comment: RAMMap may be helpful. It may be a mapped file. The exact details may help you locate the exact culprit.

Comment: Turns out it was the hardware acceleration feature that somehow leaked memory that was not associated with Firefox anywhere. thanks for the help!

Comment: There's a good chance the issue is in your video driver. You might want to check if you have the most recent driver for your hardware. But it could also be Firefox itself.

Comment: So... I had a bit of a mare anyways, since after a Windows Update, I got very frequent BSOD's, that were associated with driver failures. I reinstalled everything from fresh, which solved the issue. However, I still cannot use Firefox acceleration without this issue.

Answer (score 0):

TBH I'm not aware of a Windows way of limiting RAM except what is described [here in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1263090/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-memory-usage-of-a-particular-process-on-windows). Basically that is also what I would try. You are probably right that every application is now taking more memory as there is now more available but not infinitely more. So the only way might be limiting memory consumption for the most consuming processes.

There might be a better way but this is a good starting point :-). Also I would check the detailed RAM usage under the Windows Resource Monitor (run or search **resmon**) of your processes.