# Reserve memory in Windows for closing high-memory programs

Tags: windows, memory

I am writing a program that runs out of memory and, as a result, begins paging memory repeatedly. I can't stop the program as the computer becomes unresponsive.

Is there a way in Windows to reserve RAM space for the Task Manager or terminal so that it remains available if a running program uses too much memory?

Comment: In modern Windows very good apps manage the memory to work in harmony with Windows. I have not seen an app run out of memory for many years. Perhaps work on your own app to manage memory better. I think that is the best approach.

Comment: No offense.. this sounds like a poor coding problem, not an "access the task manager" problem.  Think through what you are creating in tight loops.  Sometimes, it can be a simple as moving the creation of an object outside of a loop.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Not everyone can create perfect programs in the first iteration, Señor. Moreover, on a Mac I am able to access the terminal to kill the task so it seems to me to be an "access the task manager" problem.

Comment: I honestly didn't mean to insult you.  If you love mac.. use mac.. it doesn't change the problem ( I code for Windows,Linux, and Mac ).  I am just trying to give you some good advice (the point of this site).  Use the debugger on ANY code you write and you will spot the flaws before they happen. Think about where the memory is going. People who don't walk through their code with a debugger every time don't write good code as well as those who do.  Good luck sir, I truly mean it.  I hope you solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open a `cmd.exe` before you start your program and type

```
taskkill /IM <your appname.exe>
```

(replace  by the executable name of your app). **Do not press <kbd>↵ Return</kbd>**, just leave the console as it is.

Then start your app and switch back to the console.

If something goes wrong simply hit the <kbd>↵ Return</kbd> key. If Windows is heavily swapping this might take some seconds until taskkill is finally executed. But as you only have to press <kbd>↵ Return</kbd> you don't need to wait for an UI response. Just hit and wait until Windows has executed the command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This kind of workaround is what I'm currently doing but was hoping there would be a better way. This problem doesn't seem to affect Macs so much.

Comment: @Cobbles Alternatively you could try to limit the maximum amount of RAM the process uses: https://superuser.com/questions/1263090/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-memory-usage-of-a-particular-process-on-windows