# is it possible to limit memory for my afk profile under 512MB in minecraft?

Tags: memory, java, gaming, minecraft, memory-limit

I want to use an AFK profile in Minecraft, but I can't seem to limit its ram usage. i tried using these JVM arguments: `-Xmx512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M`, but it gives an error saying it 'couldn't create a java virtual machine' (1)

I tried 'process lasso' from this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1263090/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-memory-usage-of-a-particular-process-on-windows), but just like the other software, I couldn't find how to limit ram for only one app, and not all apps

ps: I don't use the actual launcher, I use [this](https://mc-launcher.com/special/minecraft.html) because I used to use it before getting Minecraft and got used to it. and for multiple instances, I use [multi-mc loader](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-tools/1263013-launcher-multi-mc-loader)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmvyx.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft requires 2GB of memory to function. You probably are limiting it so much that when you try to launch it, Minecraft tries to allocate the minimum amount of memory but you have only set aside 512MB, so it throws an error and doesn't launch.

Try changing `-Xmx512M` to `-XmX2G`and it should work.

Comment: Source: https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4409225939853-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Installation-Issues-FAQ

Comment: i get the same error with ```-XmX2G```

Comment: Have you tried using the standard Minecraft launcher? Could be something about the third-party launcher.