# How to deal with huge pagefile (committed memory) usage created by ASUS LightingService?

Tags: windows-11, asus-laptop, virtual-memory, memory-management, swap-file

I have an Asus TUF Gaming laptop that I have owned for around a year. I am running Windows 11 on it.

Recently, I noticed a significant increase in memory usage, specifically from higher page file utilization. After some investigation, I identified the Asus "LightingService" process as the culprit. Whenever I stop this particular service, there is a release of at least 10GB of page file usage.

This appears to be a problematic memory leak with LightingService. The service is required for Asus Armory Crate to control the RGB lighting and other hardware integration on my laptop. However, allowing LightingService to run rampantly is bloated my page file and impacting performance.

I am wondering if anyone else using Asus gaming laptops have observed similar excessive memory utilization from LightingService? Additionally, does anyone know of a solution that would allow LightingService to operate without the severe memory leak issues?

Ideally, I would like to restrict the page file impact of LightingService specifically or somehow resolve the underlying memory leak problem so Armory Crate can function without degrading laptop performance.

Comment: You might test the memory app Intelligent standby list cleaner, https://www.wagnardsoft.com/content/Intelligent-standby-list-cleaner-ISLC-v1030-Released, which will free memory *for well-written programs*.  Also check if Asus has a new version of that app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just tried it but it did not work as I expected. Nothing happens to the committed memory value purging standby list !

Comment: It seems Process Governor (https://github.com/lowleveldesign/process-governor) is doing so. 

Ref:
https://superuser.com/questions/1263090/is-it-possible-to-limit-the-memory-usage-of-a-particular-process-on-windows

Comment: Unless you can use a different version of the Armory Crate which does NOT have this memory leak, I see no way forward, to using the software while the memory leak exists in the software. So what version are you running? [Good luck the memory leak has exists for 3 years.](https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUS/comments/l8nw2c/lightingserviceexe_handle_leak_fixed_now_moved_to/?rdt=45621)

Comment: What version of Windows 11 are you running?  There might be a native solution to your problem, but outside that, it appears paid or free alternative software to Armory Crate is the solution.  I will of course absolutely NOT make a software recommendation.  [I found at least 2, options, while performing research on the subject](https://www.bing.com/search?q=SignalRGB+Aura+Sync&qs=ds&form=QBRE)

Comment: Armory Crate 5.7.9.0 on Windows 11 Enterprise 23H2 (22635.2915)
@Ramhound

Comment: This is pretty universal problem for most of asus HW with aura service right now... My laptop had been crashing apps / GPU drivers / chromium tabs since ~20th dec 2023. At first I thought some Win update was the culprit. I had to completly restart my laptop twice a day, but since disabling "ASUS AURA SYNC lighting service" - the issue went away. Great job Asus.
(Also running latest W11 build, everything - Armory crate, asus services, gpu & chipset drivers, bios up-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

I just created this account to inform you with my "solution", click on Windows Icon and search for Services => search for: Asus Aura Sync Lighting Service => Right click on properties => Stop the process and set startup type to manual.

This way, Asus Aura Sync won't bother you in the future unless you open it to select another keyboard lightning effect then it might give you the memory issue in which case just open the service and stop it, right now after doing these steps and launching asus armory, this service started running but with 0 memory usage (my keyboard effects are static btw)

How it is for me now:

[image: How it is for me now]

20 gb cached memory usage for this service before:

[image: 20 gb cached memory usage for this service before]

0 cached after I opened armory crate and service launched without opening aura creator or changing effect with keys:

[image: 0 cached after I opened armory crate and service launched without opening aura creator or changing effect with keys]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, manually monitoring and stopping LightingService is unsustainable. I'm looking for a permanent solution that restricts LightingService's excessive paging file usage.

Does Windows provide any built-in functionality via Group Policy Objects, resource governance, or other native tools to automatically limit a process's memory/paging impact?

Comment: @FarshidNasrollahzadeh - If you need a permanent solution that involves using the service, you will then have to report the problem to ASUS and wait until they fix the problem with the service.

Comment: I'd suggest disabling the service completely... Just turn off the RGB completely, and/or use alternative open source RGB SW. I set a static darkest red color for my whole laptop - at the very least the FW on my notebook remembers the last RGB setting even without a SW running on the OS side.

Disabling the lightingService completely will make "armoury crate" crash couple seconds after turning it on. That's something I can live with.